# Anomaly Detection in Categorical Data

Tags: outliers, trend, anomaly-detection, change-point

I want to build a system that will detect Anomaly for categorical data. I have a timeseries data like this
[image]
For metric data these anomalies are calculated

1. Outliers detection
2. Trend
3. Pattern
4. Change

I have no idea **what & how do I need to calculate for finding anomalies in categorical data**. Result for the table may look like something "Everyday at 10am there is success, but today it is failure" related to these.
Can someone give me some lead, so that I will get started on this.

Comment: Trend, change. .. : are you looking at time series data? Everyday... : maybe even time series with repetitions?

Comment: Yes Ute, It is a timeseries data

Comment: This is important information. Although one can guess it perpaps from the table you show, it would help if you give this information literally in your question :-)

Comment: Updated the question. Thanks for pointing that

Comment: Great! If you are at the very beginning and need inspiration, your magic Google key word is "categorical time series". You can add "anomaly detection" to it

Comment: I tried searching and reading answers on StackExchange and Medium etc, none of the answer helped me. So posted it here. If you can refer me to any articles/answers that will help.

Comment: Hope someone knows an out of thw box solution :-) you could also refer in your question to the Stackexchange articles you have read. This shows that you have done research and is highly appreciated in this forum.

Comment: Did you also find these related discussions?
[Anomaly detection for in  time-series with categorical data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/610281)  ||  

[time series patterns for categorical variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/371945)  ||  
[How can time series analysis be done with categorical variables](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/54138) ?
It is difficult to give an answer because your question is quite broad. For example, "outliers" for time series can be defined in many ways. Such as time intervals with unusually many events.

Comment: I might actually have some ideas if you only have binary outcomes, success and failure. Perhaps your data describe a point process. Where do the times originate from? Is it the results of more or less regular checks of a system? If yes, how many checks per hour / day, and how many failures on average per day, roughly?